# Change a year in pandas dataframe if it is lower than 1900

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have to process data where someone has been using a date value with a year of 1700 where there is not an actual event date. 1700 breaks datetime, which starts at 1900, but I'm sure you all know that.

I have converted the data to datetime and then tried an if statement:

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])    
if df['DATE'].dt.year.any() < 1900
    #assigning today's date
    df['DATE'] = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")
else:
    #the original date value, formatted
    df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
```

The `if` statement does not catch the `1700` and I get the error:
 `"ValueError: year=1700 is before 1900"`

pandas version: 0.18.0
numpy version: 1.11.1

Comment: Sample data would make this easier to answer.  Somebody may answer it anyway, but including it almost always increases your odds of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im having trouble reproducing this issue exactly, but have you tried:

```
df[df.DATE.dt.year < 1900] = dt.datetime.today()
df.DATE = df.DATE.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
```

Comment: This works, but how do I format the output? Adding `.strftime("%m/%d/%y")` to `df[df.DATE.dt.year < 1900] = dt.datetime.today()` gives me a type error

Comment: The second line `df.DATE = df.Date.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m/%d/%y")` will do the formatting. Since you only need to change the dates for years < 1900 this will do that first and then go through all of them and format it the way you want.

Comment: Ok,that's what I figured, I was still getting this output: `2016-07-14 15:44:26.675000` in my final file,  but I have pinned that to something later in the script. Thanks!